# Grocery CRUD always showing No items to display but shows total number grid footer

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have a problem, that I am using `Grocery CRUD` and when I list the data, it always shows `No items to display` but it shows total number of records in table

**Controller**

class manage_home extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
 }
    public function all_intro() {
   // echo "All is well";
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_table('tbl_home_information');
    $crud->columns('pk_information_id','information_title','information_status','information_added');
    $crud->fields('pk_information_id','information_title','information_status','information_added');

    $crud->display_as('pk_information_id','ID');
    $crud->display_as('information_title','Title');
    $crud->display_as('information_added','Date');
    $crud->display_as('information_status','Status');

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output, "Manage Brands");
}
}
```

[image]
**EDIT**
Scheme of my table is 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `$crud->columns('pk_information_id','information_title','information_status','information_added');` are the field names of your database tables. Try adding `$crud->set_primary_key('pk_information_id','"your database table name here"');` if your `pk_information_id` is set to primary key.

And try to declare `$this->_example_output($output, "Manage Brands");` to `$this->_example_output($output,'"your controller to view url"');`.